# Writing a program that accepts a two digit # that breaks it down

Tags: python

I am currently using Python to create a program that accepts user input for a two digit number and will output the numbers on a single line.

For Example:
My program will get a number from the user, lets just use 27

I want my program to be able to print "The first digit is 2" and "The second digit is 7"
I know I will have to use modules (%) but I am new to this and a little confused!

Comment: What are you confused about? How far have you gotten?

Comment: I don't speak Python, but there must be a substring function. Look up how to use that. It'd probably be easier than using modulus. In fact, I don't see how you would use modulus to solve this problem.

Comment: @HobbitHole -- `%` is overloaded for strings to do formatting operations.  I think it is because it shares similarities with the C printf modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
val = raw_input("Type your number please: ")
for i, x in enumerate(val, 1):
    print "#{0} digit is {1}".format(i, x)
```

Comment: Can you do the next assignment as well?

Comment: @Blender no, but sometimes people need at least direction where to go, this time i give him the solution, next time he will know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

It was not clear from your question whether you are looking to use `%` for string substitution, or `%` for remainder.

For completeness, the mathsy way using modulus operator on ints would look like this:

```
>>> val = None
>>> while val is None:
...   try:
...     val = int(raw_input("Type your number please: "))
...   except ValueError:
...     pass
... 
Type your number please: potato
Type your number please: 27
>>> print 'The first digit is {}'.format(val // 10)
The first digit is 2
>>> print 'The second digit is {}'.format(val % 10)
The second digit is 7
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was also wondering how would I make it so it would do the same for a three digit number.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the two digit number as though it were a string. It is easier to grab each digit this way. Using str() will change the integer to a string. Modulos allow you to place these strings into your text.

Assuming the user inputs 27 into the variable called num, the code is:

```
print 'The first digit is %s and the second digit is %s' % (str(num)[0], str(num)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of coding Python:

```
val = raw_input("Type your number please: ")
for i in list(val):
    print i
```

Note: `val` is read as string. For integer manipulation, use `list(str(integer-value))` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")
print("The first digit is " + two_digit_number[0] + " The second digit is " + 
two_digit_number[1])
```

You don't need modules to solve this question.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to SO. However you answer basically repeats most voted answer here. Please read other answers before providing yours. Thanks